# It wont print out the code at the bottom on the program

Tags: python

For some reason the print command at the bottom is not printing out it is just looping no matter how I put indentation as well.

```
    result_list = []
    print("Welcome to Speed Cameras")

    while 1:
        result_list.append(input("New Reading: "))
        if result_list == "END":
        break

    try:
        max_speed = max(result_list)
        min_speed = min(result_list)
        avg_speed = len(result_list) / len(result_list)

        print("Max is:", max, " MPH:")
        print("Min is:", min, " MPH")
        print("Avg is", avg_speed, "MPH")
    finally:
        print("Thanks For Submitting")
```

Comment: I just submitted a suggested edit, but can you check the indendation on the `break` statement?  Should it be part of the if?

Comment: `result_list` is a list, it will never be equal to `'END'`. Take `input("New Reading: ")` out and check the returned value.

Comment: Please update your question with the expected output.

Comment: Change to `if result_list[-1] == "END":` and indent `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 issues and both are here

```
if result_list == "END":
break
```

`result_list` is a list so it will never be equal to a string, instead you could check if the last item is END like this `result_list[-1] == "END"`

the second problem you have is indentation, your `break` is not in the `if` statement but in the `while` loop, but this doesn't seem to be the case with your error, so i think you copied your code into the question with an error

Comment: ***"not in the if statement but in the while loop"***: Rethink your statement, as it stands it throws: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code would work:

```
result_list = []
print("Welcome to Speed Cameras")

while 1:
    # you need test the input first before append it to the list and not test the list
    inp = input("New Reading: ")
    if inp == "END":
        break
    else:
        result_list.append(float(inp))  # turn your input into a number before appending


try:
    max_speed = max(result_list)
    min_speed = min(result_list)
    # len(result_list) / len(result_list) make no sense, use sum()
    avg_speed = sum(result_list) / len(result_list)


    print("Max is:", max_speed, " MPH:")  # your variable name was wrong here
    print("Min is:", min_speed, " MPH")   # your variable name was wrong here
    print("Avg is", avg_speed, "MPH")

# since you try, you should do something when you don't pass the try
# 1 there is no input at all
# 2 the input need to be numbers
except:
    print('at least one speed input is needed, or please make sure your input to be a number')

finally:
    print("Thanks For Submitting")
```

A few mistakes:

1. Test the input instead of the list, and then append it to the list
2. Need to turn input into number
3. Average speed formula need to be fixed
4. Don't forget except in try-except-finally
5. Wrong variable names inside print()

Please reading your own code a few time before post it for help. Some mistakes like variable names and avg-speed formula, are easy to identify.

Anyway hope this would help.

Comment: Please update your answer with some notes on the fixes you have made.

Comment: Answer has been re-edited, I thought comments in the code would be more clear.

Comment: Yes, that's great. A much improved answer!